# What is the role of the swap space?

Tags: partitioning, swap

This has been something that I've wanted to ask for quite a while, but I just haven't.

When Ubuntu is being installed there is an option where swap space can be assigned, at least in the custom partition option (in the other options whether it is or isn't, I really don't know). So what is the role of the swap space?

Additionally, in the System Monitor, there is an icon indicating the amount of swap that has been used. Is it the same?

Comment: See [here](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/swap.html). As far as I am concerned, it is where stuff goes if the RAM is full :-)

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/swap.html).

As far as I am concerned, it is where stuff goes if the RAM is full [image: smiley]